# How to set a background image for each fragment in an activity?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, view, android-fragmentactivity

I have a tabed view with 3 fragments.
I want to apply a background image for each fragment seperately.
so far, I can apply a bd clor by-

```
 android:background="#ff8400"
```

but if i try using

```
 android:background="@drawable/bgimage"
```

it does not work.

I tried to set it through code using

```
rootView.setBackground(R.raw.bgone);
```

as well as

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gameslay);
```

as suggested in other answers but with fail.

Searching for a solution for two days but cant find any.Many answers for this problem are remaining unanswered here.Also, one or two answered questions are not clear for a beginner like me, please help!

Comment: You are trying to set it to `@drawable/bgimage` in .xml, but to `R.raw.bgone` in code. Is this right? Are you having the same background resource two times? Are you sure it is named correctly?

Comment: first I tried from xml, then from code.not both at same time.And both from raw folder as well as drawable folder I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Put your image into the `drawable` folder, then clean your code - don't put your image into the raw folder. If that doesn't work, please try to check if your image is damaged or if you have defined two images by the same name.

Comment: I tried puting image in drawable folder and raw folder too.tried calling setting from xml as well as code.The code is compiling very well, but when I runs it there are no background displayed.Tried with 3 different images.

Comment: Is your image JEPG or PNG ? It's better to use those two kinds of Image . Try to run your project on a phone instead of emulate ?

Comment: its png, just now tried with jpg too. iam always running on phone only.this is not an issue of common flaws as you think.please try to google at least before reply.many have experienced it.